# Webview Not Working As it should

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, web

I added an webview to my android application from the website www.doriddles.com .Everything is working fine except the answers of the riddles. (Please see these screenshots to have a more clear idea of what i meant)
[This is how it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvlEa.png)&
[this is how it looks like in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InBtJ.png)
This is the code i used in the activity:

```
  WebView easyweb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.easyweb);
     easyweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    easyweb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    easyweb.loadUrl("http://www.doriddles.com/Riddles/Easy");
```

** Update:Actually , We can in no means fix this issue ourselves . This was a problem of this particular website . I switched to another Website as my source . Now everything's Perfect!**

Comment: Is it getting loaded in website properly?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly in chrome for mobile(see screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add these line and check if it is working.

```
final WebSettings  settings = easyweb.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

easyweb.loadUrl("http://www.doriddles.com/Riddles/Easy");
```

Let me know if it did not work.

Comment: But i will Give An Up vote the work and time you had put in!

Comment: Looks like some problem problem in the html code...   Not with the webview as i can see here in my device that the screen is looking same in both webview and  chrome...

Answer (score 0):

According to google. They are suggesting us to use the Chrome Custom Tabs.
It is much faster then WebView.

Check it Link : https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: Yes , but i felt it would look better when it's inbuilt with the app

Answer (score 0):

Actually , We can in no means fix this issue ourselves . This was a problem of this particular website . I switched to another Website as my source . Now everything's Perfect!